# Can i use cordova plugin in Native Android Project

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm writting a Project about get location in Android, i was do a same Project by phonegap with Cordova Plugin for get location and i feel it was great..

So, I want to use Cordova Plugin in exist Native Android Project, anyway to do this ?

Comment: No, you can't use the plugin directly if you aren't using cordova, but if you are creating a native app, you should know java, so you should be able to understand how the plugin works and use that code into your native project with a few changes

Comment: yub, i know java, where i can find the code of plugin which can use  in native project ?

Comment: hard to tell if I don't know which plugin do you want to use... But all core and most of 3rd party plugins are on github

Comment: yes, i wanna use  geolocation method of cordova plugin, anyway to find how its work ?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but short answer is Yes. You should be able to create a Cordova project:

**cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**

Then simply add the android platform:

```
cd hello
cordova platform add android
```

Cordova will create the native android project and you can program using native Android stuff and you should also be able to use the Cordova plugins if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the answear, but in this case, i had my project, now anyway to import cordova plugin to my project? it's mean use cordova plugin to existing project

Comment: Then no. If you want  to use cordova plugins you will need to use cordova and create a cordova project. You could create a blank project and then merge your existing android project into the cordova android platform. Otherwise you should do like #jcesarmobile said and use pure java for whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, a phonegap/cordova plugin consist of 3 different parts : 
1. plugin.xml file (manifest file)
2. a common javascript interface to bridging between our phonegap project with native device API, and
3. native code for each supported platform

So, in order to your case, you can find the native code for android (JAVA file) in  `src/android` from the top directory of your plugin